# Apache Wsgi Permission denied while reading from temp folder at /

Tags: python, apache, tensorflow, wsgi

I've a webpy wsgi script running which uses the inception model of Tensorflow and is being executed out of Apache. The script is executing, but it throws a permission denied error: '/tmp/some-path/some-file' while reading. It is running using the default www-data user.

Apache virtual host segment

```
WSGIScriptAlias /alias /path/path2/path3/dummy.py
<Directory "/path/path2/path3/">
 <Files dummy.py>
   Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

The dummy.py script needs to read data from /tmp folder

I used the chmod command to change permission, but still it wont work

```
sudo chmod +1777 /tmp
```

I've been searching all day, and do understand the perils of giving unrestricted access but I just need to get this web wsgi python script to work. This code runs from python terminal. Any help?

Comment: Even if your wsgi process has permission to `/tmp/` you must also grant it on the relevant subdirectories and files. Try `chmod a+r /tmp -R` to change permissions recursively.

Comment: @HåkenLid Even after trying that, I still get the same error.  Exception [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/path/classify_image_graph_def.pb'

Comment: Does the directory `/tmp/path/` exist?

Comment: Yes, it does exist.